# Custom Projection with Offset from EPSG:28350

Tags: epsg, well-known-text

our local grid has
easting offset 700_000
northing offset 7_500_000

within EPSG:28350 origin

How can I extend EPSG:28350 OGC WKT below to add the above offset?

```
PROJCS["GDA94 / MGA zone 50",
GEOGCS["GDA94",
    DATUM["Geocentric_Datum_of_Australia_1994",
        SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4283"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",117],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AXIS["Easting",EAST],
AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","28350"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the projection on line 1 to custom.
Change the false east and northing lines 15,16
Remove the EPSG definition of 28350 on line 21 as this is now a custom projection

```
PROJCS["GDA94 / Custom",
GEOGCS["GDA94",
    DATUM["Geocentric_Datum_of_Australia_1994",
        SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4283"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",117],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",700000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",7500000],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AXIS["Easting",EAST],
AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
custom_easting = -200_000 // easting_28350 - offset, 500_000 - 700_000
custom_northing = 2_500_000 // northing_28350 - offset, 10_000_000 - 7_500_000
```

Final projcs:

```
PROJCS["GDA94 / Custom",
GEOGCS["GDA94",
    DATUM["Geocentric_Datum_of_Australia_1994",
        SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4283"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",117],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",-200000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",2500000],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AXIS["Easting",EAST],
AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```